# Convert Object to Url string parameter with checks of array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object with some values as arrays.

```
let paramObj = {
    name: 'title',
    properties: [01, 02, 03],
    rooms: [01],
    city: 'cityname'
}
```

I want to convert it to url parameters like this

```
http://localhost:8080/endpoint?name=title&properties=01&properties=02&properties=03&rooms=01&city=cityName
```

I have some thing which is working fine for normal strings but I want to check if the object key has array than convert it to multiple parameters. here is my code

```
 const qs = Object.keys(paramObj)
.map(key => `${key}=${paramObj[key]}`)
.join('&');
```

Comment: What’s preventing you from checking for an array?

Comment: Hi, I am newbie I don't know how to do that in above code. if you can share any relevant links that will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) method as in the demo below. If the leading zeros are important then the array elements should be written in string format e.g. "01" instead of 01.

```js
let paramObj = {
    name: 'title',
    properties: [01, 02, 03],
    rooms: ["01"],
    city: 'cityname'
}


const qs = Object.keys(paramObj)
.map(
    key => Array.isArray(paramObj[key]) ? 
        paramObj[key].map(v => `${key}=${v}`).join('&') : 
            `${key}=${paramObj[key]}`
)
.join('&');

console.log( qs );
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to convert an object to a suitable string for use in a URL query string you can use:

> [jQuery.param()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) : Create a serialized representation of an array, a plain object, or a jQuery object suitable for use in a URL query string or Ajax request. In case a jQuery object is passed, it should contain input elements with name/value properties.

```js
let paramObj = {
  name: 'title',
  properties: [01, 02, 03],
  rooms: [01],
  city: 'cityname'
}
let params = $.param(paramObj).replace(/%5B%5D/g, '');
let newurl = 'http://localhost:8080/endpoint?' + params;
console.log(newurl);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```